# Getting most searched for terms using C#

Tags: development, search, searchserviceapplication, analytics

Could anyone please help me with an issue I am having, I need to use C# to return the most searched for terms to put into some html. I have an on-premise Standard SharePoint 2013 environment and for my code so far I have the following:

```
public void getSearchedItems()
    {
        string siteurl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url;
        string weburl = SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl;

        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteurl))
        {
            SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
            SearchServiceApplicationProxy searchProxy = context.GetDefaultProxy(typeof(SearchServiceApplicationProxy)) as SearchServiceApplicationProxy;
            AnalyticsItemData usageData = searchProxy.GetRollupAnalyticsItemData(Guid.Empty, site.ID, Guid.Empty);

        }
    }
```

The issue I an having is with the **'AnalyticsItemData'** I am getting a no overload for method **'GetRollupAnalyticsItemData'** I have tried multiple methods for this but I keep getting the same error.

If anyone could give me any advice on where I am going wrong or how best to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!